# How to fix directory traversal security vulnerability in C# asp.net?

Tags: asp.net, security, owasp

[Find Snapshot here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tuHzV.png) While running the [IBM Security AppScan] tool for one of my asp.net mvc web applications, I am getting path traversal vulnerabilities in my code. Please see snapshot attached and sample code to understand the issue better. Is there a way to fix such issues?

Sample Code:

```
var storagePath = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings.Get("DOCS_STORAGE_PATH") + @"\Attachments";
var strMonth = DateTime.Now.Month.ToString().Length == 1 ? "0" + DateTime.Now.Month : DateTime.Now.Month.ToString();
var strYear = DateTime.Now.Year.ToString();
var strFolder = strYear + @"\" + strMonth + @"\";
storagePath = storagePath + @"\" + strFolder;

if (!Directory.Exists(@"" + storagePath))
{
    Directory.CreateDirectory(@"" + storagePath);
}
```

Comment: My 2 cents: if this isn't public and doesn't accept user input it should be fine.

Comment: Q: what is `@""` for?

Comment: Looks like `ToString()` is missing on one of the `DateTime.Now.Month`s.

Comment: @wazz, path is an app setting in web.config. I am getting this as a PathTraversal vulnerability while running the IBM App Security Tool. How I can get rid this issue? "@" sign is used only for path concatenation.

Answer (score 0):

You need to enforce your input validation to solve your issue.
you should validate storagePath in the first line after the reading of the configuration.

But, anyway, If the path is store in a configuration on your server, I suspect a False Postive from AppScan Source

Comment: I tried different fixes but none of them resolved the vulnerability. 

String Replace method e.g. ".." => ""
Path Combine method
Regex pattern matching etc etc

I know the code itself is safe as it is a configuration in web.config. 
But my goal is to get rid of this vulnerability in the report generated by the IBM tool.

Any idea how to do this?

Regards,

Answer (score 0):

If you are using asp.net MVC framework then you don't need to worry about directory traversal at-least for the config files, dll , cshtml files etc. IIS will not server these types of sensitive information at any cost. But still its always better to encrypt your config files if it has some sensitive information like password , connection string etc ..

It's better to encrypt the machine key and connection string info in config files for ease of use.

The next point if the files we save our self, it may be in database or in server path.
In both cases we have to be careful about the attacks. Not only `directory attack` but also `file upload attack`.

> If your file share is readable by the user that your app pool is
> running under (Network Service by default) you can remove the virtual
> directory completely and create an ASP.NET(any framework)application
> that will stream the files to the browser. If you're using `MVC` it's
> simply returning a file result. This has an added benefit in that you
> will be able to restrict the users from downloading the files

Note : Since you are taking the path from web.config doesn't meant that, the files under that path are safe against directory attack. If a hacker somehow get the path , then he can try that directly in the browser\hacking tools\etc.. So the objective should be to secure the files not the path

Simple idea is to create another application/method which is capable of serving the file stream based on request. There you can validate the user and serve the file, file can even be saved in database or file system (there app pool user's doesn't have direct access)